# Submit bug report without a mouse

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I've been trying to use the IDE without resorting to a mouse and I've been quite successful so far. Except when the IDE identifies an internal problem and a red button blinks at the bottom right of the IDE. And then I need to use the mouse to click there and get to the "IDE Fatal Errors" dialog, so I can submit the bug report.

[image]

How can I get there without using a mouse?

PS: I'm on windows